# Programming assignment help for Programming with a Purpose Coursera course

Tags: java

I am taking Programming with a Purpose on Coursera, an "Intro to Java" type course provided by Princeton, and have made it to week 8 so far (out of 10 weeks).

I am stuck on their "Kernel Filter" assignment and the forum for this particular course it completely dead.  Rather than write out the prompt for the assignment since it would entail a lot of text, I'll provide a link to [to the problem description page](https://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/assignments/oop1/specification.php)  (again, this is the Kernel Filter assignment).

In addition, they provide hints on an FAQ page [here](https://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/assignments/oop1/faq.php).

I have written code that appears to solve the filter kernel, provided below:

```
public static Picture sharpen(Picture picture) {
    int width = picture.width();
    int height = picture.height();
    Picture target = new Picture(width, height);

    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            Color color = picture.get(col, row);
            Color color1;
            Color color2;
            Color color3;
            Color color4;

            if (row == 0) color1 = picture.get(col, height - 1);
            else color1 = picture.get(col, row - 1);
            if (col == 0) color2 = picture.get(width - 1, row);
            else color2 = picture.get(col - 1, row);
            if (col == width - 1) color3 = picture.get(0, row);
            else color3 = picture.get(col + 1, row);
            if (row == height - 1) color4 = picture.get(col, 0);
            else color4 = picture.get(col, row + 1);
            int filterRed = -color1.getRed() - color2.getRed() + 5 * color.getRed() -
                    color3.getRed() - color4.getRed();
            int filterGreen = -color1.getGreen() - color2.getGreen() + 5 * color.getGreen() -
                    color3.getGreen() - color4.getGreen();
            int filterBlue = -color1.getBlue() - color2.getBlue() + 5 * color.getBlue() -
                    color3.getBlue() - color4.getBlue();
            if (filterRed > 255) filterRed = 255;
            else if (filterRed < 0) filterRed = 0;
            if (filterGreen > 255) filterGreen = 255;
            else if (filterGreen < 0) filterGreen = 0;
            if (filterBlue > 255) filterBlue = 255;
            else if (filterBlue < 0) filterBlue = 0;
            Color filterColor = new Color(filterRed, filterGreen, filterBlue);
            target.set(col, row, filterColor);
        }
    return target;
}
```

Clearly, while it would do the trick (or so it appears when I run it), this is not very pretty code to put it lightly.

Looking at the FAQ page provided above, one of the suggestions is to write a "helper" method kernel to do the matrix multiplication.  I have started attempting to write out code for such a method but am stuck and feeling like there has got to be a simpler way to do it.

The following is what I have so far:

```
private static Picture kernel(Picture picture, double[][] weights) {
    int vertDistance = weights.length / 2;
    int horizDistance = weights[0].length / 2;
    int width = picture.width();
    int height = picture.height();
    Picture target = new Picture(width, height);

    for (int col = 0; col < picture.height(); col++)
        for (int row = 0; row < picture.width(); row++) {
            int filterRed = 0;
            int filterGreen = 0;
            int filterBlue = 0;
            Color color = picture.get(col, row);
            Color kernelColor;
            for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < weights[0].length; j++) {
                    kernelColor = picture.get(col - vertDistance, row - horizDistance);
                    filterRed += kernelColor.getRed();
                }
        } 
}
```

I feel like there should not be 4 for loops nested inside each other (the IDE is even warning me this suggests poor program design) and I feel like this is complicated enough that a bug is almost inevitable while I'd have no hope of testing to find where any bugs could be.

This course has gotten to be challenging, which isn't necessarily a bad thing, but help does not seem to be available through the course forum. Am I on the right track for this program?

P.S.
As a consideration, with this being an "intro" type course, I believe the intention is for us to write code that is limited to the novice level i.e. for loops, if statements, basic objects (i.e. Color and Picture), etc.

Comment: Since you need to go over every x and y coordinate of your input image and use every x and y coordinate of a kernel with arbitrary size, using 4 loops is perfectly fine and required. Extracting the inner loops into a separate method (that returns the new color value for a given pair of x and y coordinates from the source image) would be an option to reduce the cognitive complexity, though. Mind you that it does not make the program any faster. (Such filtering operations are good candidates for parallelization, a more advanced programming topic that can help improve the performance again.)

Comment: Posting tips: questions here are received a bit better if they are succinct (I have not downvoted, but apparently four people did). While we appreciate things can be hard for beginners, tales of woe ("hopeless", "struggling", "no help available elsewhere") seem to attract downvotes, in my experience. Questions written with some succinctness (technical writing) tend to fare better.

Comment: Also, keep questions narrow - "please help me write the best program for this" is rather broad, and appears to be an invitation to rewrite the whole thing. I have tried to make this more specific (what adjustments are needed) but I wonder if it could be made more specific still.

Comment: Understood, I will take a look to see if I can progress any further and think of a more focused question to submit.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on condensing your `sharpen` method.  I created a skeleton `Picture` class so the code would compile.

I pulled some of the `sharpen` code into a helper method, `sumColorValue`.  I rearranged the summation formula to make it clearer to a reader of the code what's happening.  The three dots after the int tell the method to treat the individual color values input as an int array.

I also used the conditional operator (?) to shrink the process that gets the subscripts of the surrounding pictures.

Try not to just copy code segments.  See if you can create a method that you call multiple times.

Here's the revised code.

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class TestBed {

    public class Picture {

        private int width, height;

        public Picture(int width, int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public Color get(int column, int row) {
            return null;
        }

        public void set(int column, int row, Color color) {

        }

        public int width() {
            return width;
        }

        public int height() {
            return height;
        }

    }

    public Picture sharpen(Picture picture) {
        int width = picture.width();
        int height = picture.height();
        Picture target = new Picture(width, height);

        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
            for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
                Color color = picture.get(col, row);

                int previousRow = (row == 0) ? 
                        height - 1 : row - 1;    
                int previousColumn = (col == 0) ?
                        width - 1 :col - 1;
                int nextColumn = (col == width - 1) ?
                        0 : col + 1;
                int nextRow = (row == height - 1) ?
                        0 : row + 1;

                Color color1 = picture.get(col, previousRow);
                Color color2 = picture.get(previousColumn, row);
                Color color3 = picture.get(nextColumn, row);
                Color color4 = picture.get(col, nextRow);

                int filterRed = sumColorValue(color.getRed(), 
                        color1.getRed(), color2.getRed(),
                        color3.getRed(), color4.getRed());
                int filterGreen = sumColorValue(color.getGreen(), 
                        color1.getGreen(), color2.getGreen(),
                        color3.getGreen(), color4.getGreen());
                int filterBlue = sumColorValue(color.getBlue(), 
                        color1.getBlue(), color2.getBlue(),
                        color3.getBlue(), color4.getBlue());

                Color filterColor = new Color(filterRed, 
                        filterGreen, filterBlue);

                target.set(col, row, filterColor);
            }

        return target;
    }

    private int sumColorValue(int... color) {
        int value = 5 * color[0] - color[1] - color[2] - 
                color[3] - color[4];

        if (value > 255)
            value = 255;
        else if (value < 0)
            value = 0;
        return value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this.  I will not do a copy/paste, I will look through this code and see if I'm able to use it as a way to help me get to the solution.  Thanks again.